# Is there a way to stop my blue bar divs to stop randomly appearing elsewhere on the page?

Tags: html, css, position

[The correct thing to happen is the blue bar at the top, wrong at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKB5E.png)

```
.main_blue_bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #021199;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
}
```

I tried changing the position to absolute and the bottom tag to 15.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, could you expalin your question in more detail?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and it's a bit hard to explain. The blue bar in the large black div on the left is in the correct position, but it is also appearing in one of the smaller divs. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
bottom:15px;
```

To:

```
top:15px;
```